# how to select and echo an image from mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to get information from mysql including a blob image which i shall echo with php and will have an onclick event within the php, redirecting it to another page. The onlick event will contain a mysql result which it will carry with it as seen in the code below.

My main issue is with the syntax of the code or if there is another way to do it all together. please keep in mind the output when the script is run is similiar to that of google images, bing images etc. Thank you.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","media");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY  `movies`.`title` ASC");

echo "<table border='3' style='margin: auto; text-align: left;background: white;      padding: 3em;'>
<tr>
<th><b>Movie Title</b></th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<th><b>Language</b></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td style='padding-right: 2em;'><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .  base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '"  width="160px" height="200px";" onclick="window.location='lookup.php?pattern=" . $row['title'] . "';>";
</td>
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but here is one way you could clean up your code move style and javascript (and use some jquery) into the head:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","media") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY  `movies`.`title` ASC");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('img').each(function() {
                    var img = $(this);
                    img.click(function() {
                        window.location="lookup.php?pattern=" + img.attr('title');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            table {
                margin: auto;
                text-align: left;
                background: white;
                padding: 3em;
                border: 2px solid #000000;
            }
            table tr td {
                padding-right: 2em;
            }
            table tr td img {
                width: 160px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Movie Title</th>
                <th>Language</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," .  base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . "\" title=\"" . $row['title'] . "\">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ";
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Or if you don't want to use javascript, you could always wrap the image around the anchor tag instead:

```
<td>
  <a href='lookup.php?pattern={$row['title']}'>
    <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," .  base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . "\">
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Can't believe you made this off the top of your head!

Answer (score 0):

You could further separate PHP and HTML code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","media");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY  `movies`.`title` ASC");
?>
<table border='3' style='margin: auto; text-align: left;background: white;      padding: 3em;'>
    <tr>
        <th><b>Movie Title</b></th>
        <th><b>Language</b></th>
    </tr>
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'
             . base64_encode( $row['image'] );
?>
<tr>
  <td style='padding-right: 2em;'>
      <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>"
          style="width: 160px; height: 200px;"
          onclick="window.location='lookup.php?pattern=<?php echo $row['title']?>;'"
      />
  </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<?php
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You could also use some sort of templating engine to do this, but the results would be pretty much the same - I don't see much point in writing, say,

```
     <strong>{{ title }}</strong>
```

instead of

```
     <strong><?php echo $title; ?></strong>
```